# is it possible to mask everything but not "filename" in some directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've got directory with many different files with same extensions and I want to add only some files from this directory and mask the rest. I know that I can just do not add them without masking but it's better for tortieseGit to have everything masked there.

So is it possible ? Can gitignore make exceptions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ignore all files with extension .txt, but not ignore a.txt, just put this in .gitignore:

```
*.txt
!a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, git can ignore exception with a `!`. So ignore everything but foo add

```
*
!foo
```

in you .gitignore file